# Emacs: can't open load file for windows.el, possible char encoding error

Tags: emacs, encoding

I am trying to install `Windows Mode` from here: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/WindowsMode and I am having issues with loading the `windows.el` file upon initialization, where the minibuffer tells me `Cannot open load file: windows`. After saving the file, I added this to my init file:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/workspace/emacs/.emacs.d/elisp/windows.el")
(require 'windows)
(win:startup-with-window)
(define-key ctl-x-map "C" 'see-you-again)
```

And here is where I saved the file:

```
[lucas@lucas-ThinkPad-W520]~/workspace/emacs/.emacs.d/elisp$ ls -la
total 296
drwxr-xr-x  4 lucas lucas   4096 Apr 20 01:06 .
drwxr-xr-x 14 lucas lucas   4096 Apr 20 01:14 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 lucas lucas  31502 Mar 29 21:40 multi-term.el
-rw-r--r--  1 lucas lucas  35201 Apr 20 01:01 revive.el
drwxr-xr-x  3 lucas lucas   4096 Mar  9 14:57 theme-changer
drwxr-xr-x  3 lucas lucas   4096 Mar 29 01:05 themes
-rw-r--r--  1 lucas lucas 115222 Apr 20 01:06 windows2.el
-rw-r--r--  1 lucas lucas  96830 Apr 20 01:01 windows.el
```

I suspect the character encoding, which is listed at the top of the `windows.el` file (full file on the link) as `-*- coding: euc-jp -*-`. Initially saving this file gave me an error (see below), prompting me to specify the encoding. I tried saving the file as `euc-jp` then again as `utf-8`, but I still get the `Cannot open load file...` error.

Here is the message that I get when trying to save:

```
These default coding systems were tried to encode text
in the buffer `windows2.el':
  (japanese-iso-8bit-unix (13580 . 65533) (13581 . 65533) (13582
  . 65533) (13583 . 65533) (13584 . 65533) (13585 . 65533) (13586
  . 65533) (13587 . 65533) (13588 . 65533) (13589 . 65533) (13590
  . 65533))
However, each of them encountered characters it couldn't encode:
  japanese-iso-8bit-unix cannot encode these: � � � � � � � � � � ...

Click on a character (or switch to this window by `C-x o'
and select the characters by RET) to jump to the place it appears,
where `C-u C-x =' will give information about it.

Select one of the safe coding systems listed below,
or cancel the writing with C-g and edit the buffer
   to remove or modify the problematic characters,
or specify any other coding system (and risk losing
   the problematic characters).

  utf-8 gb18030 utf-7 utf-16 utf-16be-with-signature
  utf-16le-with-signature utf-16be utf-16le iso-2022-7bit utf-8-auto
  utf-8-with-signature utf-7-imap utf-8-emacs
```

Assuming that the encoding is the source of the problem, how can I setup my emacs to be compatible with these encodings?

Comment: As an alternative, you might consider using Emacs 24.4 (or a dev snapshot until that is released soon).  You can use Emacs desktops to save and restore frame and window configs.  And you can do the same without desktops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`load-path` is a list of *directories* in which to look for elisp libraries.

Use this:

```el
(add-to-list 'load-path (expand-file-name "~/workspace/emacs/.emacs.d/elisp"))
```